# React Native - Build successful but no APK output

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to build my react native app but when I run `./gradlew bundleDebug` or `./gradlew bundleRelease` it says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` but there is no APK in `build/outputs/apk` directory.
How can I build a universal APK from my react native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by using `./gradlew assembleRelease` command.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clean the gradle first then run the command `./gradlew bundleRelease`
otherwise use following command into your project directory.

```
  1. cd android && ./gradlew clean
  2. cd ..
  3. npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to react-native and I use expo. If you are new to app react-native development, try installing expo and letting them handle the build process.

How to install expo onto existing react-native project: https://jablog.online/blog/2020/01/22/existing-react-native-project-on-expo/

Answer (score -1):

Just try to generate APK from Android Studio. It is the best and the most stable way. You can find lots of articles about generating APK from Android Studio.

If you still want to generate APK from command line here is the command to run:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

If you need a more detailed article:
https://www.instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/